# How to single click and select text?

Tags: windows-7

I am having a issue I have never experienced until recently, I believe (hoping) it is just a setting I can change?

The issue:

When I left click and hold the left mouse button down and slide the mouse around to select text in a document or webpage, it works as far as selecting the text, however when I release the left button , it does not stop selecting more text.  Instead I must hit the left button again to stop it from selecting more text.  This is very annoying, at first I thought I just had a faulty mouse but I just bought a new mouse and it is the same problem.

I am running Windows 7 Professional.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Though you've solved your initial issue, it might not be such a bad idea to go into your mouse settings and change them accordingly. In that case, you can customize your button settings to your comfort.

Answer (score 0):

I think I might've fixed this, I found a setting called "click Lock" and it was turned on. I turned it off and it seems to have fixed my problem. I'm not sure how it ever got turned on though in the first place